# Using S to go to the proper indentation

Tags: key-bindings

I would like to do a mapping so that when pressing `S` at the start of a line in normal mode it automatically goes to the correct level of indentation. Here is what I have so far:

```
" S to go to the proper indent in normal mode
nnoremap <expr> S   (col('.') == 1) ? 'ko' : 'S'
```

However, this also inserts a newline (from `o`). What would be the best way to do the above mapping without inserting a newline? One option I suppose would be to first delete the current line, so:

```
'ddko'
```

**Update**: seems the following would be the correct way to do it (and would work without the conditional as well):

```
nnoremap  S   S<C-f>
```

Actually, the above doesn't work on python programs (`C-f` doesn't do anything), so perhaps using the hackish `ddko` might be the best way. My current mapping is:

```
nnoremap <expr> S   (getline('.') =~ '\S') ? 'S' : '"_ddko'
```

Comment: this is already the default behavior, but we need more details- file type, indentation settings, etc

Comment: @Mass I'm trying this on a few different filetypes -- vim, python, etc. Indentation is set to `autoindent; expandtab; tabstop=4; sw=4`

Comment: OK, I see what you're looking for now.  `=` doesn't do it for you?

Comment: @Mass -- nope, I also tried using `cindent` and that didn't either.

Comment: @Mass this post suggests using `ddko` but that seems pretty hackish: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7137730/651174

Comment: Does ddO not work instead of ddko?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble seems `ddO` doesn't always work -- I think `o` or `O` takes the indentation cue of the line it's one, so sometimes being on the line underneath doesn't always get the correct results (or at least, for me in python `ko` seems more reliable than `O`).

Comment: @David542 yeah I could see that for python specifically